# Random lodash "TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value" on Node.js application startup, can't find solution

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I was working on a webapp and at some point VSCode decided to not make me work again.

Everything was working just fine. I have been developing and debugging on my local machine until yesterday night.
Then I went home.

Then this morning, when I started the debugger on VSCode, nothing will run, and instead an Exception was thrown.

Here is what was reported:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
  at c:\Users\myusername\workspace\checkinwebbackend\node_modules\lodash-compat\internal\isHostObject.js:10:30
  at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\myusername\workspace\checkinwebbackend\node_modules\lodash-compat\internal\isHostObject.js:19:2)
  at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\myusername\workspace\checkinwebbackend\node_modules\lodash-compat\lang\isNative.js:2:20)
```

I literally did not do anything. Came to work. Started the project and bam, exception. Everything was working fine till yesterday night.

Things I tried to do:

- Reboot, didn't work
- There was a Windows update available. I installed it and rebooted. Didn't work.
- Removed all my VSCode extensions. Didn't work.

This problem already happened to me a month ago. I couldn't figure out what the problem was. I ended up formatting the PC and using Visual Studio Code Insiders.

What should I look for to solve this problem?

My environment:

- Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- Node v8.1.0
- VSCode 1.18.0 Insider x64